# Preserve creation (birth) date of converted video

Tags: video

I have a lot of old video files. When I convert them they get new creation (birth) date. Then sorting and searching doesn't 'work' anymore.

How to preserve creation date of original video also in converted video file? Even better if it can preserve all information? Perhaps even just replace video and audio data with converted video and keep all other data?

Comment: What does this have to do with the Windows 10 Microsoft Media Creation Tool?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple methods that come to mind.  The simplest is that you **name** the video with the date/time, such as `Emmas-birthday-20190722.mp4` and use the filename to establish the date the video was taken.  If you want your dates to be sortable, then perhaps use `20190722-Emmas-birthday.mp4` instead.

The other method involves (gasp) **backing up your files** before you start the conversion process.  Then after you've converted them all, you can set the converted files' timestamps back to the values of the original files in your backup.

Defining a function makes that easy.  This example use syntax that works in FreeBSD.

```
setdate()
{
  # set file $1 to have same timestamp as file $2
  touch -t $(date -r "$2" "+%Y%m%d%H%M.%S") "$1"
}
```

Here's a sample usage of the `setdate` function:

```
$ ls -ltTr
total 10
-rw-------  1 jim  jim  405 Jul 22 14:12:52 2019 foo
-rw-------  1 jim  jim  361 Jul 22 14:13:06 2019 bar
-rw-------  1 jim  jim    0 Jul 22 16:17:06 2019 farkle
$ setdate farkle bar # sets timestamp of file 'farkle' to be the same as 'bar'
$ ls -ltTr
total 10
-rw-------  1 jim  jim  405 Jul 22 14:12:52 2019 foo
-rw-------  1 jim  jim    0 Jul 22 14:13:06 2019 farkle
-rw-------  1 jim  jim  361 Jul 22 14:13:06 2019 bar
```

So if you backup your files first:

```
$ mkdir backup
$ cp -p *.mp4 backup/
```

Then after you've converted them all you can:

```
$ for i in *.mp4; do setdate "$i" "backup/$i"; done
```

Not only that, but if one of your conversions goes sideways, your irreplaceable video of Emma's birthday is still safe in the `backup/` directory.

Comment: 4) in my case the original file is 2016-12-31 23.59.49.mov. The name has space after date yyyy-mm-dd, then the time hh.mm.ss
The converted file is 2016-12-31 23.59.59.mp4
There are about 1000 of these pair files.

5) I don't understand what you explained - I don't even know what to Google it. Do I insert that function in the command line or do I have to save it in a file and then run it as a script?

6) does that setdate() sets a creation date or modify date?

I'd be grateful for additional explanation.